# Hiding a windows form that was created by a different thread in an windows form application

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I am building a windows application which has about 5 forms in it and my application has a timeout at which point it hides all the forms that are open and  navigates it to a `Login` Form. I have a `collection` which stores all the forms that are open and I loop through the `collection` and hide the forms listed in the collection.

But, one of my forms is invoked by a different thread which throws the following exception which is obvious when trying to Hide it.

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'frmVerify' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on
```

I have the following code to try and hide all the active forms

```
            try
            {
                string[] strFormCollections;
                Form objFRMMain = null;
                strFormCollections = new string[htFormCollections.Count];
                int intFormNumber = 0;

                IDictionaryEnumerator ideForms = htFormCollections.GetEnumerator();
                while(ideForms.MoveNext())
                {
                 objForm.Hide();    
                 }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayMessage(ex);
            }
```

I tried replacing `objForm.Hide()` with `objForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(objForm.Hide));` but this one threw `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute`

**May I know a better way to handle this?**

Comment: Are you, by any chance, removing the form from the htFormCollections when it's hidden?  If so, that would be why the collection modified exception is thrown (in other words, it's because you succeeded)

Comment: No I am not removing any form from the collection as you can see from the above code.

Comment: The above code does not show all your code.  Perhaps you have something in the forms themselves that remove themselves from the collection when hidden or closed, but that's not code you've shown us.

Comment: I do have an event for form closing which when triggers removes the form from collection but I do not have any event for form hiding

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I wasn't pretty sure on why the collection is being updated because all I have is `private void frmVerify_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveFormCollections(this);
        }`

Comment: FormClosing is called when you hide the form.

Comment: Well in that case, I do have same event for all other forms too for which but frmVerify is the only form thats throwing the exception and this is the only form that is running is a worker thread. I used `if (InvokeRequired)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's something tied to an event that's triggered when one of those forms gets hidden that's causing the collection to change. You were right to use the `Invoke()` method, but you'll have to hide the forms outside of the enumeration on the collection. An easy way to do that is to just `.ToArray()` the collection:

```
foreach (var objForm in htFormCollections.ToArray())
    objForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(objForm.Hide));
```

Comment: htFormCollections is a hashtable and it doesn't have ToArray() and I would prefer not to alter the existing functionality

Comment: @Dev You should be able to just add a cast operation: `htFormCollections.Cast<Form>().ToArray()`.

Comment: Hmm. I thought it just complicates because objForm should be of type form to be able to perform a Hide.

Comment: @Dev It's necessary to call `.Cast<Form>()` because `HashTable` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I thought it was an invalid cast because it throws `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'` exception